# Vagrant permission to provision.sh denied on osx

Tags: vagrant, vagrantfile

I have an issue related to running a box on OS X with a Vagrantfile/provision previously tested successfully on Windows. The box has the particularity of running Ansible entirely on the VM, but I think the problem comes way before.

```
# -*- mode: ruby -*-
# vi: set ft=ruby :

Vagrant.configure(2) do |config|

  config.vm.box = "ubuntu/trusty64"

  config.vm.hostname = "rubicon.vm"

  config.vm.provider :virtualbox do |vb|
      vb.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--cpus", "2" ]
      vb.customize ["setextradata", :id, "VBoxInternal2/SharedFoldersEnableSymlinksCreate/vagrant", "1"]
  end

  config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 8888, host: 8888
  config.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.33.10"

  config.vm.synced_folder ".", "/vagrant"

  config.vm.provision :shell,
    :keep_color => true,
    :inline => "export PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1 && export ANSIBLE_FORCE_COLOR=1 && cd /vagrant && ./provision.sh"
end
```

I get an error at the provision step:

```
/tmp/vagrant-shell: line 1: ./provision.sh: Permission denied
```

To verify that (1) provision.sh was found and (2) the user should be root and have all permission, I modified the provision line with:

```
:inline => "cd /vagrant && ls -al && echo $USER &&  ./provision.sh"
```

The output was:

```
==> default: drwxr-xr-x  1 vagrant vagrant  204 Aug 12 10:06 .
==> default: drwxr-xr-x 23 root    root    4096 Aug 12 10:12 ..
==> default: drwxr-xr-x  1 vagrant vagrant  136 Aug 11 14:28 ansible
==> default: -rw-r--r--  1 vagrant vagrant  767 Aug 11 14:35 provision.sh
==> default: drwxr-xr-x  1 vagrant vagrant  102 Aug 11 14:30 .vagrant
==> default: -rwxr-xr-x  1 vagrant vagrant  785 Aug 12 10:06 Vagrantfile
==> default: root
==> default: /tmp/vagrant-shell: line 1: ./provision.sh: Permission denied
```

So nothing surprising there.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to grant execute permissions on provision.sh

```
chmod +x provision.sh
```

Comment: Looks like it is working. Thanks a lot! I guess it was more a misunderstanding about Linux file system than vagrant itself. Isn't the root user able to execute anything and everything by default?

Comment: A file must have execute permissions for anyone to execute it.  You may use source somefile.sh if the file does not have execute privileges, but that's more typing.